# MYSQL syntax error using LIMIT in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I'm running some simple MYSQL statements from within a Java application. I'm getting a syntax error on a statement that seems to run fine if I run it directly against the MYSQL server through Navicat. The statement that is giving me hassle is:

`@NamedQuery(name = "Image.findDefaultByTest", query = "SELECT i FROM Image i where (i.test_id = :test) LIMIT 0,1")`

The error I get is:

`Syntax error parsing the query [Image.findDefaultByTest: SELECT i FROM Image i where (i.test_id = :test) LIMIT 0,1], line 1, column 48: syntax error at [LIMIT].`

Just to give an example of a statement on the line above that does work:

`@NamedQuery(name = "Image.findByLocation", query = "SELECT i FROM Image i WHERE i.location = :location")`

Any help on this matter would be much appreciated, the only information I can find on this through Google appears to be from 2003!

Comment: change `(i.test_id = :test) limit 0,1` to `i.test_id = :test limit 0,1` ?

Comment: That's what it was originally and it didn't work either, I thought that I'd try to stick it in brackets in case it was doing something weird with :test and LIMIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@NamedNativeQuery` instead of `@NamedQuery`.

`@NamedQuery` is for hql queries.

Check this 
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-named-query-examples/

LIMIT does not work in HQL it seems.